# while read loop always false - bash

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop

probably quite easy question for you but has been a while I'm stuck with this issue.
Basically i want to perform some operation in every csv file in a folder and i put together this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.csv ;
    do

         echo $file #check
         OLDIFS=$IFS
         IFS=","

         while read  var1
         do
               echo $var1        
         done < $file
         IFS=$OLDIFS
done
```

The csv files follow all the same format, 1 line and 12 variables like:

```
name,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11
```

It seems to me that the while conditions is always false and never run.
Could you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Looks like it should work. What shell are you running it on ? How do you run it? Where do you run it and where are the csvs, are they in the same directory ?Do you get any output at all ?

Comment: Double quote your variables: `done < "$file"`

Comment: What is the output from running this script? Do you see it output any filenames?

Comment: If the file has just one line, `read` will read that line and put the entire contents in `var1`. The next read will fail. Are you expecting to iterate over the fields one at a time?

Comment: @User112638726 I'm using bash shell, I run it like ./script.sh , the csvs are in the same folder and as output I see all the csvs contained in the folder.

Comment: @DanieleAvancini Can you give an example of one of the names of the csvs, do they contains only character and numbers ?

Comment: @chepner I'm expecting to get the value contained in the first field (in this name) and print it out for each csv.

Comment: @User112638726 
1NPR1, 6.3, 13.8, 12.0, -2.5, -131.9, 19.2, 8.1, 0.1, 5.9, -0.2, 0.6
characters and numbers.

Comment: You should not do this with that kind of `for` loop. Instead, do this: `find -name '*.csv' -exec my_function "{}" \;` Where you implement a bash function `my_function` and here `$1` will be the name of the file including path. Perhaps this will solve your issue.

Comment: @choroba "$file" doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: your file is called things like `-2.5.csv` then ?

Comment: @ShellFish I will use your approach thanks, but why my approach doesn't work?

Comment: @User112638726 Sorry completely misread the question: ax-bend.csv, buckle.csv ...

Comment: Might have trouble when files contain whitespaces or newlines in their name. Although I doubt this will change your issue here...

Comment: @DanieleAvancini: What does this script get you? `for file in *.csv; do echo "$file"; while read -d, -r var1; do echo "$var1"; done < "$file"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get just the first field, you need to supply *two* arguments to `read`; the first for the first field, the second to hold the remaining values after the split.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.csv; do
    echo $file #check
    while IFS=, read name rest; do
        echo "$name"        
    done < "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It reads the file into an array, splitting it at every `,`. It the iterates over the array and prints out each element on a new line.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.csv
do
    echo "$file" #check

    IFS=',' read -a vars < "$file"

    for var1 in ${vars[@]}
    do
        echo "$var1"
    done
done
```